# Which Element or CSS selector to use for custom CME logo?

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme, templating

In previous versions of SDL Tridion, you could add a logo to the Content Manager Explorer by updating the CSS (see [my example on TridionDeveloper](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/where-am-i-skinning-the-sdl-tridion-content-manager-explorer)).

Specifically, you could add a `background-image` to these CSS selectors:

```
.tridion .abouttridion .button,
.tridion .abouttridion .button.mouseover,
.tridion .abouttridion .button.mousedown
```

It looks like the .abouttridion class has been replaced with the personal information center.

I've left a comment on [SDL Documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-5E30FE46-721D-40EA-AB4D-DC96917EE306), but what element would you recommend for adding a logo-type image to the interface?

Answer (score 6):

A few options, starting with the easiest:

- `.frame-navigation-logo` is the class used to render the SDL logo in the slide-out sidebar. It currently uses a background image to render an image sprite that contains the SDL logo at the top left corner of the image. You'd have to create your own instance of that sprite, and modify it. I feel that this is Tridion 2013's spiritual successor to the image that used to be displayed in the top right corner of the primary CME UI.
- The user bar can be modified fairly easily. `.userinfobar .post-core` is the class of an empty DIV with an ID of "Post_ExtendableArea". Seems like a solid invitation to *extend* it! You won't be able to do much with this beyond a basic logo graphic about the size of an icon without disrupting the rest of the top nav and user bar, but something like this should suffice to get you started:

  ```
  .userinfobar .post-core {
      float: left; /* Part of the default Dashboard.css */
      width: 18px;
      height: 18px;
      background-image: url(https://placehold.it/18x18);
      margin: 6px 6px 7px 21px;
  }
  ```
- Beyond those options, however, I'm not seeing an obvious overridable purely CSS solution, which leaves a fairly solid opportunity to create a GUI extension for possibly injecting some markup into an existing DOM element. If this is your chosen path, maybe consider the right hand side of the `#DashboardToolbar` DIV (would make use of the empty space on the right-hand side of the ribbon toolbar; placing it into this DIV means the logo would be visible regardless of which toolset chosen from the top nav)?

Comment: you've had some strong coffee today @rob :) (bow)